# Synergy "L" Shape using Laptop on bottom and an iMac with second screen across top

Tags: macos, mac, display, mouse, synergy

I've used Synergy successfully before, but now I'm trying to make an "L" shape with my laptop on the bottom, and an iMac with second screen across the top.

With the laptop (server) located below the iMac (client) in Synergy's configuration, the system spreads the connection point from the top of the laptop across the bottom of both the iMac and it's second screen. So for instance, if I move the mouse out of the right half of the top of the laptop screen it goes to the iMac, and if I move the mouse out of the left half of the top of the laptop screen it goes to the iMac's second screen.

I'd like the top of the laptop to simply connect with the bottom of the iMac screen, basically making an "L" configuration of screens. Thanks!

Comment: Please include your synergy config (`.sgc` IIRC) in the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature we're working on, it'll allow you to independently position your screens on a grid in any configuration. We're planning to release this in Synergy 2.1 (I work on the Synergy dev team at Symless).